# SQL database access access

Tags: sql

I can get to where I can view databases in my sql, however I want to see what is in those databases? what is my next command?

Comment: What's your sql database server and where is it running?

Comment: This question needs a lot of clarification. `I can get to where I can view databases in my sql` which exact step you get stuck at ? is it `show databases;` statement as in steeldriver's answer ? ` want to see what is in those databases`, what exactly you want to see ? list of tables ? dump whole database contents ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have got as far as

```
show databases;
```

then the next step would be to choose a specific database

```
use database_name;
show tables;
```

See [Getting Information About Databases and Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-information.html)